# Separar uma string em blocos conforme semelhança

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte desafio proposto:

> input: "aaaaabbbbccccccaaaaaaa"
>
> output : "5a4b6c7a"

E fiz o seguinte código para solucioná-lo:

```
def conta_numero_letras(string):
    armazena = ''
    for letra in string:
        if letra not in armazena:
            armazena += str(string.count(letra)) + letra
        else:
            pass
    return armazena

print(conta_numero_letras("aaaaabbbbccccccaaaaaaa"))
```

E a minha saída está sendo: 12a4b6c
Como eu faço para analisar por blocos a string, para obter na saída a quantidade de cada bloco individualmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diovana, fiz o seguinte código para resolver o problema, nele tem alguns comentários explicando como o código funciona:

```
def conta_letras(string):
  #Pego o tamanho da string para verificar string vazia e também para o loop
  tamanho = len(string)

  #String vazia, retorna vazio...
  if tamanho == 0:
    return ""

  contagem = "" #String que contém a contagem de letras, string de retorno da função
  letra_atual = string[0] #Primeira letra da string
  quantidade = 0 #Contagem de letras

  for i in range(tamanho):
    #Se a letra for a mesma da anterior, aumenta a contagem
    if letra_atual == string[i]:
      quantidade += 1
    else:
      #Se a letra mudou, adiciona a contagem e a letra a string de retorno
      contagem += str(quantidade) + letra_atual
      #Reinicia a letra atual e a contagem
      letra_atual = string[i]
      quantidade = 1

    #Caso seja a última letra do loop, finalizo a contagem
    if i == (tamanho - 1):
      contagem += str(++quantidade) + letra_atual

  return contagem

print(conta_letras("aaaaabbbbccccccaaaaaaa"))
print(conta_letras("abcdefgh"))
print(conta_letras("zzzzaaaabbbbccccbbbbaaaacccczzzz"))
print(conta_letras("xptoaaabbb___zzxzz"))
```

Comment: Sua resposta está basicamente correta - mas com um sotaque "não Pythonico" (chegando ao ponto de ter código que simplesmente não é Python e não vai fucnionar como você queria - `str(++quantidade)` não adiciona "1" em "quantidade" - não é um erro de sintaxe por que aplica duas vezes o operador de "número positivo `+` na variável, mas seu valor não muda). Mas principalmnte em Python nao se costuma usar `for` por índices, exceto quando realmente necessário - já que o `for` natural da linguagem é um "for each" que já fornece o elemento da sequência de dados diretamente.

Comment: Opa, meu intuíto foi deixar o código realmente bem explícito e com uma sintaxe que pode ser aplicada em outras linguagens, pois parece ser o caso de alguém que está começando a programar, por isso os comentários etc, valeu! :)

Comment: Estou começando, acertou! Sua explicação foi super didática, os probleminhas na sintaxe que podem provocar errinhos são fáceis de mudar. Muito obrigada pela ajuda! :)

Answer (score 1):

O problema com seu código é que ele conta *todas* as ocorrências de uma dada letra na string, independente de sua posição (o valor retornado pelo método `count`) -  e não leva em conta blocos separados com a mesma letra.

Pra constar, esse algoritmo é chamado de "run length encoding" (RLE), e é um algoritmo de compressão ainda usado em muitos tipos de arquivo básicos que usamos no dia a dia (por exemplo, imagens GIF, e imagens em postscript).

Bom - a solução é usar mais variáveis de estado - pra ao percorrer letra a letra da string original, poder olhar "para trás" e ver qual é a última letra - e tomar uma ação caso seja igual a atual, e outra caso seja diferente.

Uma outra coisa para se ter em mente é que em Python, strings são objetos imutáveis. Então, embora nesse caso, a performance não seja relevante (de qualquer forma esse código vai rodar em menos de 10ms para strings menores que umas 30 páginas de texto), é melhor que os dados mutáveis do código sejam construídos numa estrutura "mutável", como uma lista, e depois que tudo estiver coletado, "congelados" numa string de saída. Para esse "congelamento" a chave é o método ".join" das strings, que usam uma lista como entrada.

A sua função pode ficar assim:

```
def rle(input_str):
   count = -1
   previous = None
   result = []
   for char in input_str:
       count += 1
       if char != previous and previous != None:
            result.append((count, previous))
            count = 0
       previous = char
   if previous:
      result.append((count + 1, previous))

   output = ''.join((str(pair[0]) + pair[1]) for pair in result)
   return output
```

Comment: jsbueno, seu código não funcionou quando a string de entrada é por exemplo abcdefg, ele conta apenas a primeira letra e as demais ficam com zero.

Comment: Uma possível correção seria antes do append, verificar se o count na verdade está com o valor zero, por exemplo:
#Código anterior
else:
  if count == 0:
    count += 1
  result.append((count, previous))
  count = 0

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta! Ainda estou começando a programar, então torna-se um pouco complicado entender alguns conceitos usados no algoritmo.

Comment: @daniel - correçoes feitas - estava com pressa - o importante é somar 1 toda vez, a soma estava um carácter "atrasada".